# Calculating and collecting the terms of the zero component of the Einstein’s tensor

Tags: physics, tensors, differential-geometry

I try to calculate the  $G_{00}$ of the Einstein tensor
$G_{\mu\nu}= R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R$

for the metric:

$g_{00}=-a^2(\tau)\left( 1+2 \phi^{(n)}\right),$

$g_{0i} = a^2(\tau)\left( \partial_i  S^{(n)} \right),$

$g_{ij}= a^2(\tau)\left[(1 -2 \psi^{(n)})\delta_{ij}+\left(D_{ij} \chi^{(n)} \right)\right]$

Where $D_{ij}=\partial_i \partial_j - (1/3) \delta_{ij}\partial^k\partial_k$

So that, $\phi$ and $\Psi$ are scalars, $S$ is a vector, and $\chi$ is a tensor.

I got $G_{00}$ as:

```
FullSimplify[Eins[[1, 1]]]


(1/3)*((9*Derivative[1, 0][a][t, y]^2)/a[t, y]^2 + 
   n*(6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 0, 0, 4][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 2, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 0, 4, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      2*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 2, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      2*Derivative[0, 4, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]) + 
      (1/a[t, y])*(n* Derivative[1, 0][a][t,y]*(-6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
              6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
        18*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
        Derivative[1, 0, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
              Derivative[1, 0, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
        Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])))
```

The question is that I try to interpret $G_{00}$ or write it in Latex format, hopefully, all the terms are correct, I mean all the terms should be scalars because $G_{00}$ is a scalar quantity. Looking at the MA code output `Ein[[1,1]]`, let us consider the common terms:

- How to tell MA that

  `(-6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] -6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]`

equal $\partial_i \partial_i S $ ?

- Also there are similar $\Psi$ terms, how to collect them and call them $\partial_i \partial_i \Psi $?
- Finally $\chi$ terms, indeed I wonder if those terms are correct or not, because how to write a term like
  `Derivative[0, 0, 2,2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]`
  as a scalar? Also why there are forth derivative terms
  `Derivative[0, 0, 0,4][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]` although a Linearization has been done for the equations.

**Edit**

To help examine $G_{00}$, I add here the code which I calculated by:

```
x = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}; 
met = a[t, y]^2*{{-(1 + 2*n*\[CapitalPhi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]), 
     n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], 
     n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]], 
     n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi]]}, 
         {n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], 
     1 - 2*n*\[CapitalPsi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {r, 2}] - (1/3)*n*
       D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 2}] - 
             (1/3)*n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], 2}], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], \[Theta]], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], \[Phi]]}, 
         {n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], \[Theta]], 
     1 - 2*n*\[CapitalPsi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 2}] - 
             
      n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {r, 2}] - (1/3)*n*
       D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], 2}], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]], \[Phi]]}, 
         {n*D[S[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi]], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], r], \[Phi]], 
     n*D[D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]], \[Phi]], 
           
     1 - 2*n*\[CapitalPsi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], 2}] - (1/3)*n*
       D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 2}] - 
             (1/3)*n*D[Xi[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {r, 2}]}}; 
metI := Inverse[met]


Chrest = ParallelTable[
   Normal[Series[(1/2)*
      Sum[metI[[i, p]]*(D[met[[p, j]], x[[k]]] + 
          D[met[[k, p]], x[[j]]] - D[met[[j, k]], x[[p]]]), 
               {p, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 1}]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 
    4}]; 

Reim = ParallelTable[
   Normal[Series[
     D[Chrest[[i, l, j]], x[[k]]] - D[Chrest[[i, k, j]], x[[l]]] + 
      Sum[Chrest[[i, k, m]]*Chrest[[m, l, j]], 
               {m, 1, 4}] - 
      Sum[Chrest[[i, l, m]]*Chrest[[m, k, j]], {m, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 
      1}]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}]; 

Ricci = ParallelTable[
   Normal[Series[Sum[Reim[[m, i, m, j]], {m, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 1}]], {i, 
    1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]; 

RScal = Normal[
   Series[Sum[
     Sum[metI[[i, j]]*Ricci[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}], {j, 1, 4}], {n, 0, 
     1}]]; 

Eins = ParallelTable[
  Normal[Series[
    Ricci[[i, j]] - (1/2)*met[[i, j]]*RScal, {n, 0, 1}]], {i, 1, 
   4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: *$G_{00}$ is a scalar quantity*. One component of a tensor is not a scalar.